# Sphinx, SUM(@weight)/@count

Tags: group-by, sphinx

I have a very specific query I am currently doing with MySQL

My Table structure is :

```
id : INT, primary KeY, AUTO_INCREMENT
occupationID : INT
alias : VARCHAR(255)
```

Then, I do a

```
SELECT occupationID, (MATCH(alias) AGAINST ('Web Developer' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) / count(*)) as score FROM aliases group by occupationID order by score DESC LIMIT 0,2;
```

This query performs a search on every ROW, doing a full scan, and divide matches by their number of occurrences. This way, I got an average score on all rows, giving me the accuracy I need.

This is very slow (20 sec) , with a 50k records table . ( I am not surprised, MySQL fulltext is very slow...).

With Sphinx, I was thinking to build an index with this query:

```
select id,occupationID,alias, (SELECT count(*) from aliases AS A WHERE B.occupationID=A.occupationID) as nb   from aliases AS B
```

And then do a

```
$sphinx->setSelect("@id, sum(@weight)/nb as score");
$sphinx->setGroupBy("occupationID", GROUP_BY_ATTR, "score DESC");
```

and

```
$sphinx->query("Web Developer");
```

Am I doing this right?

Comment: After testing, this works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly. The only odity I spot, is in the original mysql, you group by occupationID. But in building the index you join with id - meaning the count will be the number with the same id, not the sample occupationID.

I'm also not certain that sum(@weight) works in sphinx - in theory it should, but there are a few odd restrictions, so cant be sure without testing.

Comment: You're right, I am fixing this occupationID typo. My Bad. I will test the sum(@weight) today, and I will let you know the results.